# How to diff two specified revisions?

Tags: c#, svn, sharpsvn

I want to know the modified files between two revisions by using SharpSvn .

I only want to list filenames and path, not the file contents if possible.

Comment: Are you ***writing*** your own client? SharpSvn is just the .NET API which is used by such things as AnkhSvn and CollabNet Desktop Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to use it in `SharpSvn` but using usual subversion you can do something like this from command line:

`svn -c revisionStart:revisionEnd`

Usually subversion wrappers just wrap already available functionality. So you can try to run from command line `SharpSvn` executable with the same parameters.

Should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out `SvnClient.DiffSummary()`

This is the SharpSvn equivalent of `svn diff --summarrize`